# Spring-boot 1.4.4 to 1.5.1 breaks autowiring

Tags: spring-boot

I have a multi-module maven project where the the spring-boot application module depends on another module that is packaged as a jar.

The spring-boot module defines an application class that is at the root package of both modules.

sprint boot application module

|- a.b.c.Application

|- a.b.c.d.RestService

another module

|- a.b.c.e.Component

In boot 1.4.4, RestService is injected (through the constructor) with the Component from another successfully. However, in 1.5.1, RestService fails with a nullpointer when it tries to use the Component. I don't see anything in the release notes that would explain this... Would could be the reason for different behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Still happening in 1.5.2...

Answer (score 0):

Service was annotated with @Validated while the method was declared as "final". This caused spring to skip creating a proxy for the method. This wasn't an issue in 1.4, so I'm guessing validation processing changed, but I didn't see anything in the release docs.